# Combobox with checkboxes on a user control?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsto

I'm working on a VSTO add-in for Excel, and one of the thing I want is to filter by sheet, and allow selecting multiple sheets. Just to share a bit more info, I potentially have over 30 sheets I need to handle.

Is there a way to add checkboxes to a dropdown, in order to filter by multiple choices?

Edit: I did try CheckedListBox combined with mouseenter and mouseleave to expand and contract the CheckedListBox, so it does not take as much space in the form, but the animations are janky, because it's set in a flowLayoutPanel with auto-size. That is why I was asking for a combobox solution, because if hovers over other form elements, and it does not require resizing the form.

Answer (score 0):

dropdown box is maybe not the best thing to use for youre purpose.I recommend you to consider this CheckedListBox control:

link to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

Comment: i did try that, combined with mouseenter and mouseleave to expand and contract the CheckedListBox, so it does not take as much space in the form, but the animations are janky, because it's set in a flowLayoutPanel that auto-sizez.  That is why I was asking for a combobox solution, because if hovers over the information, and it does not require resizing the form.